# Android tablet for preschool kid, mostly for offline use, with some specific exceptions

Tags: android, tablet

I am looking for a tablet that could replace a Fire HD 8 (2017) for my preschool child. So the use case is as follows:

- Watch offline video
- Listen to offline music and audio books
- Run a few select apps for children which require a WiFi connection
- All of the above should normally work without headphones

#### Must haves

- 8 or 10 inch screen size
- weight suitable for a preschool child to carry and throw (!) around
- 3.5 mm audio jack
- WiFi
- support for a microSD of at least 400 GB
- 2 GB RAM or more
- hardware acceleration for H.246 encoded video
- ability to root without any soldering or opening the device
- USB-C charging port (because direction doesn't matter and it's physically sturdier than micro-USB)
- decent battery life as can be expected from a modern tablet
- availability of a protective case

  - **either** readily available child-proof case (preferably one were the handle doubles as stand)
  - **or** a form factor mostly compatible with another tablet which has such a case
- availability of a *tempered glass* screen protector

#### Preferred

- 3 GB RAM or more
- ability to use Google Play Store (while rooted)
- hardware acceleration for H.246 **and** H.265
- replaceable battery
- WiFi 6 support
- Compatibility with LineageOS

#### Optional

- Cameras

#### Explicitly absent

- Any mobile internet modem

#### Price point

- Preferably below 300 €, but not *considerably* above 400 €

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend the Samsung Galaxy A7 2020 Wi-Fi. It does feature an audio jack, microSD slot and reasonable performance, and is [apparently rootable](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-sm-t500-t505-galaxy-tab-a7-10-4-unlock-bootloader-root-with-magisk.4185993/) too.

No LineageOS (yet?) support or easily replaceable battery though.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a closer look at the specs. A superficial look suggests this could be a match.